# Combining 2 GraphicsMagick commands into 1 command, like in ImageMagick

Tags: php, resources, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I was using ImageMagick to create a new resized image with watermark, with this single command (in PHP):

```
exec("convert -filter Lanczos {$original_image} -thumbnail {$max_width}x{$max_height} -quality 90 {$watermark} -gravity center -unsharp 2x0.5+0.7+0 -composite {$cached}");
```

Now I switched to GM and am looking for a way to run 1 command to do the same task. The only way I found was to split it to 2 separate commands:

```
//create the resized image
  exec("gm convert -filter Lanczos {$original_image} -thumbnail {$max_width}x{$max_height} -quality 90 -unsharp 2x0.5+0.7+0 {$cached}");
  //apply the watermark and recreate the watermarked image, overwriting the previously resized image
  exec("gm composite -quality 90 -dissolve 100 -gravity center {$watermark} {$cached} {$cached}");
```

Is there a way to combine them into 1 single command and by that maybe also reduce resources & drive usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have received the following reply on this from Bob Friesenhahn, GraphicsMagick Maintainer:

> You did not say what version of GraphicsMagick you are using. Modern 
>   versions support a '-compose' option which may be put on the command 
>   line after the input file name to remember the composition algorithm 
>   to use. This composition algorithm is then used if the -mosaic or 
>   -extent operators are used to do a composition. You can also use a 
>   -page option after the input file name to locate the image when it 
>   is composited with prior images in the list. Due to a weakness in 
>   GM's convert command processing, the -mosaic or -extent operators must 
>   be the last command prior to saving the output file. I believe that 
>   ImageMagick's -composite must be a version of -mosaic which adds more 
>   features (e.g. -mosaic might not support gravity but -composite does).
>   It seems like GraphicsMagick should implement something completely 
>   compatible with ImageMagick's -composite.
>   Regardless, there is an effective workaround available if you need to 
>   use your existing GM commands.
>   If you have a modern GraphicsMagick which supports 'gm batch', then 
>   you can use the 'mpr' coder ("Magick Persistent Registry") to remember 
>   intermediate images between commands and you can easily adapt your two 
>   commands to execute with full efficiency using the existing command 
>   lines. This Unix shell example should give you some ideas:

```
{
   echo convert seaworld.jpg mpr:temporary
   echo convert mpr:temporary crap.jpg
} | gm batch -prompt off -echo on
convert seaworld.jpg mpr:temporary
convert mpr:temporary crap.jpg
```

> Notice that the output of the first command was saved (as an image 
>   handle as natively used within GraphicsMagick) into 'mpr:temporary' 
>   and then the second command took input from 'mpr:temporary' and wrote 
>   the final output file. You can use arbitrary string arguments to 
>   'mpr:' so you can have several images "in flight".
>   With this approach you can use 'gm convert' and 'gm composite' in the 
>   same batch command.
>   I am not sure how one would best access this batch facility from PHP 
>   but if PHP can stream commands to it from a pipe, then it can run for 
>   quite a long time as a co-process to PHP and save considerable compute 
>   time and overhead.